# Does the stack pointer increment/decrement in words or bytes in a byte addressable system?

Tags: pointers, assembly, stack

Given a byte addressable system.Say the word size(= register size) is 2 bytes.The stack grows upwards and currently the stack pointer is at 0x016E.The CALL instruction is of two words,the opcode word and the other is the starting address of the subroutine.The CALL instruction works as follows :

i)load the PC,PSW onto the stack;

ii)load the starting address of the subroutine in PC.

PC contents before CALL instruction is 0x5FA0(filler info I'm assuming).What is the value of the stack pointer after the execution of the CALL instruction ?

The answer is 0x172.
So this is what I can't wrap my head around. PC + PSW + CALL = 8 bytes on stack.Or is the CALL instruction not stored on stack ? A clear sequence of events would be much appreciated.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you store a call instruction on the stack?

Comment: Usually, the only thing stored on stack when calling a function is the return address (PC). Everything else is optional. The CALL instruction in x86, for example, will just push EIP on the stack. On ARM arch, nothing is pushed on the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the listed rules you gave this should happend

**Before the call**

```
...
0x16a uuuu                          PC 0x5fa0
0x16c uuuu
0x16e uuuu <-- Stack pointer        uuuu = Undefined but allocated
0x170 xxxx                          xxxx = Undefined and not allocated
0x172 xxxx
0x174 xxxx
...
```

**After the call**

```
...
0x16a uuuu                          PC 0x????
0x16c uuuu
0x16e uuuu                          uuuu = Undefined but allocated
0x170 5fa4 (Return address)         xxxx = Undefined and not allocated
0x172 PSW  <-- Stack pointer
0x174 xxxx
...
```

I've drown the stack with increasing address toward the bottom as I'm used with down growing stack but the stack is actually growing up.

The return address pushed on the stack is `0x5fa4` because the routine must return *after* the call and at `0x5fa0-0x5fa1` there is the *call* opcode and at `0x5fa2-0x5fa3` there is the *call* operand.

Suppose that the *call* instruction is this

```
call 0x1234
```

And that the opcode for the *absolute*<sup>1</sup> `call` instruction is `0xfffe`. The memory at `0x5fa0` would be

```
...
0x5f9c ????
0x5f9e ????
0x5fa0 0xfffe <-- Call opcode
0x5fa2 0x1234 <-- Call operand
0x5fa4 ????
0x5fa6 ????
...
```

<sup>1<sub>Ignore this adjective, just make the example easier.</sub></sup>

The *push* operation is actually two operations:

1. Add two to the stack pointer
2. Store the operand at the now incremented stack pointer address

*This is why I drown the stack in words.*
*This kind of stack is called Full Ascending, as the stack pointer grown towards higher addresses and point to the last word stored.*
*I inferred this kind of stack by the answer you gave, it is not the only one, see this case for the [ARM stack](http://www.bravegnu.org/gnu-eprog/arm-stacks.html) (no assembly instructions involved).*

The *call* push the *PC*, a word, on the stack, being the stack pointer `0x16e` it is incremented by two giving `0x170` and the *PC* is stored there at `0x170-0x171`. Same thing for the the *PSW* (which I assume is a Program Status *Word*) which is stored at `0x172-0x173` with the stack pointer pointing at `0x172`.

Comment: Thanks! but im not clear on how 0x5fa0 onwards has the opcode and the operands.

Comment: @VishnuNair updated the answer with more details on the call instruction.